# How do I return the individual with the highest fitness among three in a 20 lists array?

Tags: python, list, genetic-algorithm

I'm coding a genetic algorithm. There is a population-array of twenty individuals (each of them rapresented by a list). It draws three numbers (indices) of three possible parents and chooses the one with the highest fitness (which is another list).

The issue is that in the fitness there are surely some identical values (11 possible values and 20 items...). So if I use .index() method return the first one with that value.

```py
def genitori(popolazione, fitness):
    def genitore(popolazione, fitness):
        popolazione = popolazione.copy()
        fitness = fitness.copy()
        ran_value = []
        lista = []
        lista_pos = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            ran_value.append(random.randint(0, 19))        
        print(ran_value)
        for i in ran_value:
            lista.append(fitness[i])
        vincitore = max(lista)
        print(vincitore)
        for i in fitness:
            if i == fitness[vincitore]:
                lista_pos.append(fitness.index(i))


        for i in lista_pos:
            if i in ran_value:
                genitore = popolazione[i]
                return genitore

    gen1 = genitore(popolazione, fitness)
    gen2 = genitore(popolazione, fitness)
    return gen1, gen2

fitness = [5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
popolazione = [[4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 11, 7, 7, 10, 6, 6, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 11, 9, 0, 2, 2, 10, 8, 4, 1, 9, 7, 9, 8],
 [4, 4, 5, 3, 9, 8, 11, 1, 7, 4, 11, 8, 7, 3, 3, 7],
 [6, 0, 0, 8, 10, 3, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 6, 10, 2, 3, 9, 6, 5, 4, 4, 10, 2],
 [9, 11, 3, 5, 10, 2, 5, 8, 6, 4, 11, 10, 0, 1, 8, 4],
 [2, 0, 7, 11, 1, 7, 5, 1, 5, 6, 11, 6, 4, 0, 9, 3],
 [4, 1, 8, 4, 7, 10, 6, 5, 1, 9, 10, 8, 10, 10, 4, 10],
 [2, 7, 7, 6, 6, 1, 3, 1, 7, 6, 11, 1, 3, 7, 5, 2],
 [4, 9, 3, 2, 11, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 11, 6, 10],
 [9, 5, 4, 2, 9, 9, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 7, 9, 5, 4, 2],
 [2, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 11, 0, 9, 11, 0, 2, 11, 9, 7],
 [7, 2, 0, 9, 7, 9, 5, 2, 2, 0, 5, 7, 9, 10, 9, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 9, 7, 7, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, 2, 11, 11, 9, 7, 7, 11],
 [7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 7, 9, 9, 11, 9, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 7],
 [9, 11, 9, 7, 11, 7, 11, 11, 11, 7, 11, 11, 9, 11, 7, 9],
 [4, 11, 0, 2, 0, 11, 9, 9, 0, 4, 2, 0, 11, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 9, 9, 9, 2, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 11, 11],
 [4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 9, 9, 9]]
```

I expect the output to be the list with index randomly chosen and highest fitness but the actual output is an integer.

Comment: `I expect the output to be a list` what list? can you add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to avoid `list.index()` whenever possible. I suggest you first combine population with fitness:

```
population_with_fitness = list(zip(fitness, population))
```

The `zip` creates a new list of tuples like this: [(fitness1, ind1), (fitness2, ind2), ...]. But it returns an iterator, which we have to convert to a list.

Next we take a random sample of size 3, without replacement (e.g. no duplicates):

```
import random
candidates = random.sample(population_with_fitness, 3)
```

Then sort the candidates by fitness:

```
candidates.sort()
winner_fitness, winner_genes = candidates[-1]
return winner_genes
```

This works because Python's sort() will compare the tuples element-by-element. The list will be sorted by fitness first, then by individual population members.

For a GA you may want to keep the order randomized if you expect that equal fitness values will happen. This can be solved like this:

```
candidates.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The index method of python lists returns the first index that matches. That why you don't get everything. You have several options:

1. With numpy arrays:

```
    import numpy as np

    fitness = np.array(fitness)
    best = np.argwhere(fitness == value)[:,0] # or np.argmax(fitness)
```

2. With lists (probably slower):

   `best = [ i for i,x in enumerate(fitness) if x == value ]`

Comment: So in the second case best is a list of indices, isn't it?

Comment: Both solutions are